# Creating Class Properties in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, class, ide, properties

Using the standard VS IDE, is there a fast way to create class properties that are linked to the local variables?

The class diagram seems to provide something, but it basically just created a property stub.  Is there something better / easier out there ?

Comment: Did you try "prop <tab> <tab>" in the code editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VS.NET 2008 you can use refactoring, Encapsulate field (ctrl + r, e).
Here is info about how [Refactoring In Visual Studio 2008](http://www.onedotnetway.com/refactoring-in-visual-studio-2008/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about just making quick properties, then Auto-Generated properties are 'the bomb'. There's no need for a background local variable unless you plan to do something special in the get or set.

```
 public string SampleProperty { get; set; }
```

or

```
 public string SampleProperty { get; private set; }
```

Where you can optionally specify private / protected to limit the property to a setter or getter only. Then, you don't need a local variable and you just use the Property in place of the local variable. The compiler will generate the actual background variable for you.

I think you might be confusing an Auto Generated property with a property stub.

Answer (score 0):

When building classes in Visual Studio (VS), you can generate property setters and getters quickly by defining a field variable, and then right-clicking on the field and selecting Refactor → Encapsulate Field from the popup menu. VS will display a dialog that lets you approve/change the property name, and optionally, preview changes. When you're satisfied, simply click OK. Voilà! VS generates the property!